# How do I remove a certain parent node in Firebase based on a child Cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I currently have my DB structure like this [image: firebase realtime database structure]

What I want to do is be able to loop thorugh each one that has a certain feedId, I've been trying it this way but am currently having no luck. Would anyone be able to assist?

```
function clearAllPostsInOwnFeed(userId) {
  return admin
  .database()
  .ref(constants.FBC_USERS_FEEDS + '/' + userId)
  .once('value')
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
      if (snap.child('fromId').val() === userId) return snap.remove()
      return snap
    })
    console.log(snapshot)

    return snapshot
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently returning a snapshot from the inner callback. Since that is not a promise, it resolves right away - and your function gets terminated. before it has deleted the nodes.

---

The simplest fix is to use `Promise.all()` to wait for all deletes to finish:

```
function clearAllPostsInOwnFeed(userId) {
  return admin
  .database()
  .ref(constants.FBC_USERS_FEEDS + '/' + userId)
  .once('value')
  .then((snapshot) => {
    let promises = []
    snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
      if (snap.child('fromId').val() === userId) {
        promises.push(snap.ref.remove())
      }
    })
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use a multi-path update to wipe all matching nodes with a single write:

```
function clearAllPostsInOwnFeed(userId) {
  const ref = admin
  .database()
  .ref(constants.FBC_USERS_FEEDS + '/' + userId);

  return ref
  .once('value')
  .then((snapshot) => {
    let updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
      if (snap.child('fromId').val() === userId) {
        updates[snap.key] = null;
      }
    })
    return ref.update(updates);
  })
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your comment, the first one works like an absolute charm, however I am interested in using the second one, the only issue with that is it is removing the entire node, instead of the select few with the fromId on it like the first, could I just do .child('fromId') on snapshot and somehow reference the parent still?

Comment: The second fragment should not be deleting the entire node. Are you sure you are calling `update`? And if you `console.log(JSON.stringify(updates))` right before that, does it show the keys you expect to be removed?

Comment: I am currently getting everything returned, so everything within the node, not just the node, I'll paste the data below. Despite there are only a few nodes I want to select with that fromId === userId.

{"WeL7Lw17gvYGSPr7eOoMijJHT2P2_-MmZ06VOmWM_3J9R2yQN":null,"WeL7Lw17gvYGSPr7eOoMijJHT2P2_-MmZPbFAHyJKy2Dt6nAF":null,"WeL7Lw17gvYGSPr7eOoMijJHT2P2_-MmZ018onDqvmFGXE6BP":null,"WeL7Lw17gvYGSPr7eOoMijJHT2P2_-MmZ01zrmo86CaWROmBi":null,"WeL7Lw17gvYGSPr7eOoMijJHT2P2_-MmZ0SLcPeyXA_DHtTVT":null,"WeL7Lw17gvYGSPr7eOoMijJHT2P2_-MmZ04_ZXNlFDKdr0EG9":null}

Comment: Ahh, I fixed it! Forgot to add the if between updates[snap.key]


function clearAllPostsInOwnFeed(userId) {
  const ref = admin.database().ref(constants.FBC_USERS_FEEDS + '/' + userId)

  return ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    let updates = {}
    snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
      if (snap.child('fromId').val() === userId) {
        updates[snap.key] = null
      }
    })
    return ref.update(updates)
  })
}

Thanks again Frank!

Comment: Oops, that's a good catch.  I updated the code in my answer too.